# testng data provider display current test number

Tags: testng

The testNG data provider feature reads my excel file and determines how many times to execute a test based on how many rows of data I am providing in the test.

I was wondering what are some ways to have testNg display the **current test number** and the **total number of tests** that it's running. example print statements: "I am currently running test 3 out 10", then next iteration " I am currently running test 4 out of 10."

Cheers

Comment: You want to use a TestNG Listener

Comment: A specific example with code would be helpful, esp for those of us whose Java still needs work. :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your class that has your `@Test`s, you will need to put an annotation:

```
@Listeners({TestListener.class})
public class SomeTestClass {
```

Then your Listener class will look something like the following:

```
public class TestListener extends TestListenerAdapter {
   @Override
   public void onTestStart(ITestResult result){
       ...fancy code to output...
   }
}
```

That fancy code could be different things.

`result.getParameters()` will give you the parameters that you passed into the `@Test`.  If you can use the parameters to figure out how many times you've run it so far, that would be great.

You could have a static integer that will store the current run throughs (or a static map of strings and ints that maps the test name to the number of times run.

However, I think that displaying `Running test 1 of 10` is not really that useful.  However, I *do* use listeners to output information, and I think that `result.getParameters()` and the other functions of `result` are very informative and can help you to make good output.

Comment: Thanks. when I ran this via the debugger the "result" variable returned a ton of fields. It was still tough trying to figure out which one is "test number." I'm sure it's in there though! I ended up using a very straightforward workaround in the very Excel sheet I was using to drive the test.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround that I used using Excel's data.
In the Excel sheet create a column called TestRowNumber as the first column in the test data. Use this formula in the first cell **=ROW()** and copy it into all other cells below it. This formula will automatically number each row in the Spreadsheet.

Then the Java code can look like this:

```
@Test(dataProvider = "DP_ourTest", invocationCount = 1, priority=2, enabled = true)
    public void ourTest(String... excelData) throws Exception {

//This will grab the value of the first data column (index 0) if your Excel Data. 
setTestNumber(Integer.parseInt(excelData[0])-1);


//And in a separate method or class you would set this testnumber data for each run

public static int testNumber;
// getter for TestNumber: this tells the Data source which row to start from
public static int getTestNumber() {
    return testNumber;
}
// setter for TestNumber: this tells the Data source which row to start from
public void setTestNumber(int testNumber) {
    this.testNumber = testNumber;
}
```